# The proper way to make this layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, layout

I'm studying web development for a few months now and I generally have some problems with the front-end and the UI layout. I often have difficulties placing the elements exactly where I want them. In that case, either I use relative values and break the responsiveness of the site, or I write some rules that seem to me like hacks.

For the example, let's consider this image:

[image: Example.png]

As you can see, there is a Bootstrap container, full-width background color, two classic elements inside the container and an image outside.
For this kind of layout, I'd do something like the following:

```
    <!-- /* MAIN WRAPPER -->
    <div class="pull-right">
        <img src="/img/topright_image.PNG" alt="shape">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red"> <!-- Red background color. -->
        <div class="container">
            <header class="row">
                <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-sm-2" id="logo"> <!-- I'm using Bootstrap 3, IIRC there's a better way to do that in Bootstrap 4. -->
                    <img src="/img/logo.PNG" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3" id="title"> <!-- First difficulty, how to make sure the title will always be centered without being relative to the logo and no matter its content? --> 
                    <h1>Centered title</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-green"> <!-- Multiple containers, just to have colored backgrounds at 100% width of the page. -->
        <div class="container">
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MAIN WRAPPER */ -->
```

It's a quick draft, but you get the idea. The CSS will then implement arbitrary height for the header and the section (300px and 400px), then the max-width for the container.

How to do that properly?

(And what if I want to make the logo a little above the title; between two rows?)

Comment: Depending on what you need to support, and how strict that support needs to be, [Grid Layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) is a nice option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Proper" is relative. Which makes this a tough question to answer. Using *only* TBS, this solution is how I would do it. However, I tend to favor flexbox more than TBS so I'd probably use the TBS container how you have it set up (yes, doing that to the containers is a valid way of achieving your goal. Another method I have used before, is `box-shadows`. Neither option is better, but now you know), and then handle each row as a flexbox or even just simply use floats and centering. This is not a very heavy layout.

If you are looking to learn how to do it "properly", I'd read other code. Specifically for TBS I'd recommend [Start Bootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/). It has a bunch of TBS themes you can look at. Look at the code, see how they do it, see what you like, start doing that.

Ultimately, in the end, it doesn't matter how you get there[1] it just matters that you do. This is a viable solution, and I don't see anything glaringly wrong or hackish.

---

1. It actually does matter. But you appear to still be in the learning
   phase[2] so it doesn't matter as much so long as you are willing to
   keep an open mind and correct things as they are found
2. We are all always learning.